# OdbcConnection to local DBF file fails in one application but not another

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, database-connection, dbf

Greetings stackoverflow,

I am using the following block of code in two C# projects of mine, one is a project where I prototype methods and code blocks like this, and the other is my actual project.

```
DataSet set = new DataSet();
String path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
File.Copy(path + "\\template.dbf", path + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".dbf", true);

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)}; DriverID=277;Dbq=" + path + ";"))
{
    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}.dbf", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")), connection);
    OdbcCommandBuilder builder = new OdbcCommandBuilder(adapter);
    connection.Open();
    adapter.Fill(set);

    // Database manipulation goes here

    adapter.Update(set);
}
```

In the prototyping application this code block works great while in the other project I get an OdbcException when I call `connection.Open();`. The `template.dbf` file exists in both projects, both projects copy that template file to the output build directories, the `File.Copy()` call works great in both cases, and they both use this code block verbatim but in one project it fails and the other it works fine. I've even changed the connection string in the prototyping project to work out of the build directory of the other project and it works fine.

This is the exception I receive:

`ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Also, I've tried connecting to the `template.dbf` files instead of the copied version in both projects, the prototype project connects properly and the other project fails with the same exception.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the difference between the two projects are. Is there some other code block that I could use that works in both projects that does the same thing?

EDIT: For clarification this isn't a complicated project or anything. It is just two simple Windows Console applications that I am working on in Visual Studio 2010, using the default settings provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: I wonder if this is a 32/64 bit problem? Are the two projects set for the same platform?

Comment: Both projects are set for the same platform. These are just very basic Windows Console applications that use the default compile settings that Visual Studio 2010 provides.

Comment: Several failure modes here.  Don't run this code one second before midnight.  Or on machines that have UAC enabled.  Or with paths that contain a space, you need quotes around {0}.dbf

Comment: I believe for an odbc connection you have to define a DSN within the odbc configuration in the machine which executes your code. Are they defined in both cases?

Comment: Let me add a clarification to my original post, but I'm just trying to get these projects to run in my dev environment first. I'm just executing them out of Visual Studio 2010.